# Remove a file containing space in the name with Python

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm trying to delete a file which contains a space in its name. I'm using a Mac, and escaping the space character. However it stills throws an error.

Here's a screenshot,
[image: Removing a file with space in name]

How do I fix this?

Comment: You may simply use `os.remove("/Users/karthik/Desktop/screenshot 2.png")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no need to escape the space character.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to escape the space character.

```
os.remove("/Users/karthik/Desktop/screenshot 2.png")
```